# In a simple transformer is input voltage due to the change in magnetic flux in the iron or the ac source?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

One of the solution to a question I was doing says that "Both the input (Vp) and output (Vs) potential differences are induced e.m.f. produced due to
the change in magnetic flux in the soft iron core."

However I always thought the input voltage is simply referring to the V(rms) of the ac source. In this diagram here the input voltage, 240V, is written right beside the symbol for the ac source.

Answer (score 0):

$V_p$ is the voltage across the primary which is *equal* to the applied voltage $V_s$.

To be clear, there are two equations that must be simultaneously satisfied:

$$V_p = N_p \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

where $N_p$ is the number of turns in the primary winding and $\phi$ is the core flux, and, when an AC voltage source is connected across the primary, KVL requires that

$$V_s = V_p \rightarrow V_s = N_p \frac{d\phi}{dt}$$

Since $V_s$ is the independent variable, it follows that the core flux is determined solely by the applied voltage.